# Tomcat: How to restrict access to certain Servlets URI from specific port only?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, servlet-filters

I have many connectors in my tomcat server.xml, listening on different ports.

I have many Servlets deployed in my webapp each doing different functionality.

I want to restrict some Servlets be accessed only from a specific server port, not from all the ports..

For example: I have 4 ports on which my server is listening

```
10.11.12.13:8081
10.11.13.14:8082
10.11.14.15:8083
10.11.15.16:8084
```

I want servlets with a specific URL pattern  to be able to access only through one of these server ports and block the access when try to access through a different server port, for example like below:

```
servlet URL pattern | Allow Access Server Port
/myservletreq1      | 8081
/myservletreq2      | 8081
/myservletreq3      | 8082
/myservletreq4      | 8083
/myservletreq5      | 8084
```

I can do this by writing a Filter and adding this port check, but is there any way tomcat provides to accomplish this function or any better solution than writing a Filter?